# Parametrized SQLQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, query-string

I've used LINQ in my current project, but this query seemed to complicated to desing in LINQ, so I decided to try SQLQuery.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString );
connection.Open();

string query = "SELECT dateadd(WEEK, x.WeekOffset,0) as [Week],"
       + " AVG(x.SessionAmount * x.SessionTime) as [WeeklyAverage],"
       + " STDEV(x.SessionAmount * x.SessionTime) as [WeeklyStDev],"
       + " FROM"
       + " ( SELECT datediff(WEEK,0, Session.Date) as WeekOffset, Session.SessionAmount, Session.SessionTime"
       + " FROM Session WHERE UserId = @userId "
       + " AND Session.Date >= @startDate AND Session.Date <= @endDate"
       + " ) x"
       + " GROUP BY WeekOffset"
       + " ORDER BY WeekOffset";

SqlParameter start = new SqlParameter("startDate",System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
SqlParameter end = new SqlParameter("endDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
SqlParameter uid = new SqlParameter("userId", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);


List<SqlParameter> paramColl = new List<SqlParameter>();
paramColl.Add(start);
paramColl.Add(end);
paramColl.Add(uid);

List<TempStdDev> Calc = new List<TempStdDev>();
Calc = db.Database.SqlQuery<TempStdDev>(query, paramColl).ToList();
```

I have tried several ways to implement parameters, but I keep getting different error messages, like : >"No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List`1...to a known managed provider native type."

What is the most common/standard way to support the parameters to the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the signature of SqlQuery is

```
public DbRawSqlQuery<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(
    string sql,
    params object[] parameters
)
```

Your code is getting converted in to the equivalent to

```
Calc = db.Database.SqlQuery<TempStdDev>(query, new object[] { paramColl} ).ToList();
```

Change your code to

```
Calc = db.Database.SqlQuery<TempStdDev>(query, paramColl.ToArray<object>()).ToList();
```

so the function uses the array itself instead of putting the list in the first slot of the array.

However, because the function is `params` you don't need to use the `paramColl` list at all, just pass the members themselves.

```
Calc = db.Database.SqlQuery<TempStdDev>(query, start, end, uid).ToList();
```

---

**P.S.**

```
List<TempStdDev> Calc = new List<TempStdDev>();
```

should just be

```
List<TempStdDev> Calc;
```

You create a new list then immediately overwrite it, there is no reason for the first step.